# Terraform environment variable naming conventions

Tags: terraform

Is there a particular casing convention around defining environment variables in terraform? (minor detail I know, just want to be consistent!)

I'm of the opinion, they are ultimately env vars regardless of source of where it's defined so I've always seen them as:

```
environment {
  variables = {
    MY_ENV_VAR = "foo"
    }
  }
```

On the other hand my colleague think they should be in lowercase:

```
environment {
  variables = {
    my_env_var = "foo"
    }
  }
```

I've not been able to find a definitive answers so hence the question :-)

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about env vars you want to use or the naming convention that Terraform *requires* to read env vars?

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly is that you're asking. Can you please edit your question in order to provide more details?

Comment: The plugin SDK documentation you mentioned is discussing the naming idiom for arguments in a Terraform provider, which are not environment variables and so those docs don't seem relevant to what you are discussing. With that said, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "environment variables" here because Terraform itself would never interact directly with an environment variable named `MY_ENV_VAR` or `my_env_var`.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Have updated the question apologies for the ambiguity